# Vertical Alignment Assistance

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Very simple question... may sound silly, but I've been struggling to do this for an hour.

How do I LOWER the main navigation links (HOME, ABOUT, GALLERY, etc) on this page:
http://bellairecabinets.com/new/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the top margin of the `<ul>`

```
margin-top:50px;
```

You can increase the top padding of the `<ul>`

```
padding-top:50px;
```

If it didn't work, try to increase the top padding of the items inside the `<ul>`

Comment: to <ul>? I tried adding that margin-top to "#menu-main-nav li" and it lowered the main navigation, but screwed up the drop downs. All items in the drop downs were vertically spread out...

Comment: What I meant in <ul> is the #main-menu-nav, now try to increase the top margin of it, or of the <li> inside it (Home..etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Firebug addon shows that main navigation menu (`#menu-main-nav`) has a property `margin-top`. You can just increase the margin to lower the navigation links.

A very sound long term advice for you will be to grab excellent tools like Firebug, MeasureIt, experiment and learn about CSS properties with them.

Comment: Hi Shubham, I definitely want to learn. I'm in the process.

I just added that margin-top by the way, and it's not doing anything. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this
        #menu-main-nav li strong 
                          { line-height: 35px;
                            height: 40px !important;
                         }